# Clearing zero when the value is not zero

Tags: c#, .net

I am using TrimStart('0') to clear the leading zero.

For example :

```
string value= "00999";
value = value.TrimStart('0');
```

It is working great.

But now what happen is I don't want to trim value that is zero, for example 00.

For example, the return result is 00 :

```
string value= "00";
    value = value.TrimStart('0');
```

Thank you.

Comment: Q: Are you sure you can't accomplish exactly what you want with a "Format" statement?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add this line:

```
if (value == "")
    value = "0";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (value.TrimStart('0') != "")
  value = value.TrimStart('0');
```

This will only trim the string when it contains other characters but 0.